Calculate CDF of Weibull distribution in R
I want to calculate the probability that a Weibull random variable X is greater than 1000, where X ~ Weibull(lambda, g).
Using the CDF I calculate it as:
g = log(log(.7)/log(.5))/log(40/81)
lambda = -log(.7)/400^g

> exp(-lambda*1000^g)
[1] 0.4294352

but using the R package as below, the result is different
> pweibull(1000, shape = g, scale= lambda, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0

Why are the results different? Am I using the R package wrong?

Hi @Dave2e, actually exp(-lambda*1000^g) gives the correct answer, but I am not sure how to get the same result in R.

The result is below floating-point precision, run pweibull with argument log.p = TRUE and it will give -358114.6. With a multiprecision arithmetics library exp(-358114.6) is 6.30e-155528.

Try checking against online calculators, eg.. Wolfram

From the Wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Density_function.
It looks like you are using the  first alternative of alternative parameterization.
Following the article, your lambda value is actually "B". To convert to the standard lambda, the conversion is:
lambdaNew <- exp(-log(lambda)/g)

Thus the R function becomes:
pweibull(1000, g, lambdaNew, lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.4294352

